# Ribbon customization for Alert Me

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, ribbon

Is there any way to remove `Alert Me` button from ribbon for specific SharePoint List, I can do it with CSS but i have lots of Pages to modify is there a way to write a Script in master page and disable/hide/remove the `Alert Me` button from ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/en-US/59705965-20ab-4495-a699-5c79b1af2338/how-to-add-a-javascript-to-my-seatlemaster)

and [link2](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/66fd582c-3c93-4953-8ab5-e761e4d1e14f/hide-alert-me-button-of-a-document-library?forum=sharepointgeneral)